# c++ explicit instantiation -- function templates -- replace a implicit instantiation to learn it

Tags: c++, instantiation

Im reading c++ primer plus and having some issues understanding how implicit instantiation works. I havent learned classes yet, so I am just dealing with functions. I think I understand the basics of implicit instantiation (function templates) but I just dont understand explicit instantiation. I have below a function that uses a template, can someone show me how a function like this would be written if it used a explicit instantiation. You can change the way it works, but just keep it simple. I would really be appreciative. This will help me understand the syntax, and how it is used.

```
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 
  4 template <typename T>
  5 void show(T,T);
  6 
  7 
  8 int main()
  9 {
 10   int a = 10, b = 12;
 11   char c = 'x', d = 'y';
 12   
 13   show(a,b);
 14   show(c,d);
 15   
 16   return 0;
 17 } 
 18 
 19 template <typename T>
 20 void show(T a, T b )
 21 { 
 22   std::cout << "I used the int version " << a << " " << b << "\n";
 23 }
```

Comment: oops sorry, I had been messing with it alot, and I forgot to put that in my example. Do you know how to convert this function to a explicit instantiation instead? I edited my function to show this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a `Show<int>(c, d)` Notice that I've explicitly instantiated the `int` version, but passed the `char` parameters. That's (a rather simple take on) explicit instantiation, but you might be actually referring to [explicit specialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwyxac18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: He can't be talking about template specialisation, as it doesn't exist for function templates ...

Comment: @PierreBdR - You're right, *explicit specialization* is what I was looking for. Edited. I knew that such a thing existed, just forgot what it was called...

Comment: @ Schnommus - neither, it's called explicit instantiation. Once again, specialisation doesn't exist for function templates.

Comment: @PierreBdR - Then why is there an MSDN article called *Explicit Specialization of Function Templates*?

Comment: Yes, it's only partial specialisation that doesn't exist (I got corrected), but what you have using here is really instantiation. Specialisation would mean you're specifying a different code for the template.

Comment: @PierreBdR - I know that, that's why I linked to an article that describes it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Think of templates as code generation akin to copy/paste where you replace `T` by a concrete type. "Instantiation" is the process of copy-pasting the code into your program.

Implicit instantiation happens whenever you use the template. For function templates, the concrete type is deduced from the function arguments and the template is instantiated for that type. So, your code effectively becomes:

```
void show(int a, int)   { std::cout << "I used the int version " << a << " " << b << "\n"; }
void show(char a, char) { std::cout << "I used the int version " << a << " " << b << "\n"; }

int main() { /* as it was */ }
```

*Explicit* instantiation, on the other hand, just explicitly forces the compiler to generate code. For example, if we add the explicit instantiation

```
template void show(double, double);
```

to your code, the compiler would generate the corresponding code,

```
void show(double a, double) { std::cout << "I used the int version " << a << " " << b << "\n"; }
```

This would happen no matter whether or not you actually use that code.

If you don't know about classes yet, then you're missing 92% of the fun, because class template instantiation is far more subtle. Only member functions that are actually used are implicitly instantiated, while an explicit instantiation creates code for all class members. Also, class member functions aren't checked for correctness to some degree until they actually get instantiated, so you can write templates that don't actually make sense for *all* possible types.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant specialization (which you refer explicit instantiation) for `int` then it can be as:

```
template <typename T>
void show(T,T);

template <>  // specialization (not overloading) for 'int'
void show(int a, int b)
{
   std::cout << "I used the int version " << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

If you really want to do explicit instantiation then it can be done as:

```
show<int>(a,b);
```

which is actually redundant in this case actually.

Comment: This is incorrect. You are talking about template specialisation, and it doesn't exist for template functions. Your code is actually incorrect.

Comment: @PierreBdR, the [code is correct](http://www.ideone.com/TzB8x) only. `template` specialization does exist for `template` functions. Why do you feel it is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up with partial specialisation. Also, I've never seen a case in which function specialisation is even useful.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly instantiate your function, you want to specify the type explicitly. In your example, replace the calls to `show` by:

```
show<int>(a,b);
show<char>(c,d);
```

That's it. The implicit instantiation just means the compiler can figure out the `int` and `char` from the types of the arguments.